# Python: vertical binning of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of the same size:

```
A = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
B = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]  # numeric values
```

How do I do a vertical binning?

Output desired:

```
C = [    1,     2,     3, 4, 5]  # len = 5
D = [a + b, c + d, e + f, g, h]  # len = 5
```

i.e. a mapping of `A` list to its cumulative sum (vertical binning?) where it occurs in list `B`.

Comment: a+b = 1? or 2??

Comment: does `C` simply have `A`'s unique values? Are a...h numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, C is the unique values of A:

```
C = sorted(set(A))
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now, D is the vertical binning of B w.r.t A (if B's elements are alpha):

```
D = [''.join(B[i] for i in range(len(B)) if A[i] == j) for j in C]
```

if B's elements are num:

```
D = [sum(B[i] for i in range(len(B)) if A[i] == j) for j in C]
```

gives:

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g', 'h']
```

Note:

```
A = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
B = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

Here a,b,c,... if numeric, go for the second eqn :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume `a`, `b`, ... are numeric variables:

```
bins = dict()
for b, x in zip(A,B):
    bins[b] = bins.setdefault(b, 0) + x

C = [key for key in bins]
D = [bins[key] for key in bins]
```

If `a`, `b`, ... are of another type, you would have to adjust the default value in `bins.setdefault(b, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary and since `Python 3.6` the order is preserved, therefore you get your `C` as the keys and `D` as values:

```
A = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
B = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]

from random import randint
rename_to_B_for_numeric = [randint(0, 255) for _ in A]

result = {}

for idx, item in enumerate(A):
    if item not in result:
        # not sure about the type, so...
        result[item] = "" if isinstance(B[idx], str) else 0
    result[item] += B[idx]

print(result)
# {1: 'ab', 2: 'cd', 3: 'ef', 4: 'g', 5: 'h'}
print(list(result.keys()))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(result.values()))
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g', 'h']
```

obviously if the type of item in `B` is not a string nor a number (`int` in this case) you'll need to modify the code a little bit to get some default type. Or just use `else`:

```
    if item not in result:
        result[item] = B[idx]
    else:
        result[item] += B[idx]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect case for the use of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

fst = itemgetter(0)    
A = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
B = [1,3,4,6,7,7,8,8]

C = []
D = []
for k, v in groupby(zip(A, B), key=fst):
    C.append(k)
    D.append(sum(item[-1] for item in v))

C
>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

D
>>[4, 10, 14, 8, 8]
```

If `B` is a list of strings then your summation operation becomes:

```
D.append(''.join(item[-1] for item in v))
```